# ColdFusion 9 Cluster with IIS7.5

Tags: windows, coldfusion, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, cluster-computing

Does anyone know of a step by step process of setting up a ColdFusion 9 cluster using IIS 7.5?  Either failover or network load balance would be nice.  Without IIS being clusterable in Windows 2008 R2, I'm not sure of the best means to configure the web server and ColdFusion service.  Some of the things I'm looking for are.....

1. With load balancing, what do you use out in front of the servers as a load balancer?
2. If you're using a network share on a clustered file server for the website data files, how do you configure the ColdFusion service to run so that it has network access instead of running as Local System?

Comment: Are you trying to set up a set of *stand-alone* CF9 instances behind a load balancer each running in Win 2008 R2? And do you have an actually load balancer to use, or are you going to be using DNS round-robin?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of running CF with network access, you need to change the user that is running the CF9 service in the Services Panel.

Go to *Administrative Tools -> Services*. Then right-click on the *Coldfusion 9 Application Server* service and choose *Properties*. Then click the *Log On* tab.

There you can run it as the local user or specify another user. This user should have the rights to access the network resources you speak of.